# How can I use a different camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to make a basic game to practice some unity scripting. How can I add a new camera to my scene? I have created a cube as my main character and dragged a camera script from the store onto my cube but it says no cameras rendering.

Comment: you have to choose the render display for each camera (in the properties of the camera component). Display 0 is your main screen, Display 1 your 2nd screen and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean with "dragged a camera script from the store"

Instead, after you added your cube, select it and in the inspector (normally on the right side of your editor), click "add component" and type in "camera" and select the camera component